# Jquery saying that object doesn't support 'each'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

When I run my web app, I get an error saying that "JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'each'", I'm trying to create a legend below or above my jquery slider...

here is the scripts I'm using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
```

and this is my JQuery script

```
$(function () {

      $("#slider-range").slider({

          range: true,

          min: 0,

          max: 100,

          values: [0, 100],

          animate: 'slow',

                        slide: function (event, ui) {
              //$(ui.handle).find('span').html('$' + ui.value);
              //
              $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);

                            }
          .each(function() {

                                // Get the options for this slider
              var opt = $(this).data().uiSlider.options;

              // Get the number of possible values
              var vals = opt.max - opt.min;

              // Space out values
              for (var i = 0; i <= vals; i++) {

                  var el = $('<label>'+(i+1)+'</label>').css('left',(i/vals*100)+'%');

                  $( "#slider" ).append(el);

              }
          })
      });

      $("#amount").val("$" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +

        " - $" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));

  });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Tip: if you format that code properly you should see the error right away.

Comment: You know I always wondered why the code looked like a mess, I should have been properly formatting it. I mentioned below that I'm new to JQuery

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org/ is helpful

Answer (score 0):

You are applying `each` on the options object, which only has `range`, `min`, `max`, `values` and `animate`. Indeed, no `each`.

Comment: So what I missing to have a 'legend' be above my range slider?

Answer (score 0):

You were calling `each()` on the slide handler function - misplaced `})`

```
$("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    values: [0, 100],
    animate: 'slow',
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        //$(ui.handle).find('span').html('$' + ui.value);
        //
        $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);

    }// <-- you had it here
}).each(function () {
    // Get the options for this slider
    var opt = $(this).data().uiSlider.options;
    // Get the number of possible values
    var vals = opt.max - opt.min;
    // Space out values
    for (var i = 0; i <= vals; i++) {
        var el = $('<label>' + (i + 1) + '</label>').css('left', (i / vals * 100) + '%');
        $("#slider").append(el);
    }
});
```

Comment: I fixed what you were talking about, but when I ran it I got another error  JavaScript runtime error: cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'values'

Answer (score 0):

You are calling [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) at wrong place you need to do  `}).each(function () {`

```
$(function () {
    $("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        values: [0, 100],
        animate: 'slow',
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            //$(ui.handle).find('span').html('$' + ui.value);
            //
            $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);

        }
    }).each(function () { //you each loop like this

        // Get the options for this slider
        var opt = $(this).data().uiSlider.options;

        // Get the number of possible values
        var vals = opt.max - opt.min;

        // Space out values
        for (var i = 0; i <= vals; i++) {

            var el = $('<label>' + (i + 1) + '</label>').css('left', (i / vals * 100) + '%');

            $("#slider").append(el);

        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this has stopped the errors, but the label is not showing up. Forgive me I'm new to JQuery

Comment: @user2970223 change you var `el` like this `var el = $('<label>').css('left', (i / vals * 100) + '%').text(i + 1);`

Comment: I changed as you suggested, but no label...this may sound stupid but am I supposed to add something more to my css file?

Comment: @user2970223 No you don't need to.Do you get any error on console ?

Comment: No, no errors at all. the page loads and I'm able to move the range slider handles. No label showing up.

Comment: I got it figured out now, its working. The only problem is when the legend appears it doesn't span evenly the length of the slider